# Efficiency of calling array.length in javascript

Tags: javascript

Most looping examples I see in javascript use the `array.length` property in the for loop itself, like so:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  // do something
}
```

However, sometimes I see the `array.length` property being written to a variable, and then the variable value is used in the loop, instead:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
var len = numbers.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  // do something
}
```

Coming from a C# background, I've never had to worry about this. However, in Javascript is the second method more efficient and why?

Comment: you might want to take a look at this: http://jsperf.com/fastest-array-loops-in-javascript/30

Comment: thanks, that's a good link.

Comment: Note that aside from efficiency, these two differ in terms of what happens if the array changes length during the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is more efficient because it does not have to make an operation on anything. In the first, it just has to reference a data cell each time.